# Why doesn't this silent launch work in WIX?

Tags: wix

I have the following command running at the end of my package install for an application.

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[INSTALLDIR]RCR.VDS.exe" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA"
      DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="no" />
```

I can't use [#myApplication] because I run heat on my output folder on my build server so I don't know the auto generated id of my application.  Any ideas on how to silently run my application after the install?

The log file shows this for the command line section

```
******* CommandLine: **********
```

MSI (c) (30:74) [09:47:14:156]: Note: 1: 2203 2: VDSInstall.msi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (30:74) [09:47:14:156]: MainEngineThread is returning 2

Comment: You need to describe the symptoms and post an installer log to get detailed advice. Otherwise, I can merely provide you with a RTM answer.

Comment: BTW, this is why I don't use programs like Heat to autogenerate my installer.  It's pretty damn important that my file keys and guids don't change from build to build.   That is if you ever care about upgrades and patching. (You should.)

Comment: I do.  There is an inherent trade off between having all the files included, and having problems like this and upgrades.  Is there a better way to solve the first problem without screwing the second?  I know that is a completely different question than the original.

Comment: I don't advocate dynamic dependency analysis or dynamic code authoring, period.  I've learned from 16 years of setup development that the first step of creating an installer is understanding your dependencies and the second step is authoring the optimal way to deploy them.  I minimize the friction (http://iswix.codeplex.com) but don't turn on the autopilot and turn off the brain. (PS- Spare me the argument of authority commentary.)

Comment: Authority commentary?  I ask questions because I want to learn something.  I apologize if it came off as something other than that.

Comment: Sorry, not you.  Let's just say on more then one occasion I've had developers want to use dynamic installation authoring.  Guess I'm getting old and jaded.

Answer (score 2):

Please see: [How To: Run the Installed Application After Setup](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm)

If you want the custom action called during a silent install add:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize">SOMECONDITION</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Note SOMECONDITION should be an expression that checks the EXE is installed and the user wants the program to be launched.

Comment: I am trying to do a gui-less launch.  This part of the manual only has a GUI version.  And it uses  [#myApplication] which I explained why I can't use it.

Comment: [#fileKey] and [DIRECTORY]FileName.exe will evaluate the same.  That example answered the story of giving the user a choice to run a program at the end of the installation while running interactively.  If you want to run it silently, you need to schedule the custom action in the InstallExecuteSequence.

Answer (score 1):

The are a copy things you can consider:

1. The identifier from `heat.exe` will be stable. So you can use the ugly identifer in your `[#UglyFileId1234abcef45612345asdf]` custom action.

   a. You could also apply a XSLT to transform the `heat` output for the executable file's Id to something nicer than the ugly identifier. Depends how readable you want the launch custom action to be.
2. If you want the executable launched silently then you'll probably want the [Quite Execution custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) instead of the [Shell execute custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/shellexec.htm) that "LaunchApplication" uses.

Comment: Rob- I tried the following and the msi errored out.  If you can point me to more useful logs than the default one I will be glad to provide them.

Comment: I thought I pasted in what I tried. <Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value="[#cmpBE7B7EEC48ECEEFB32AEA6219EDAB9C7]"/>
      <CustomAction Id="QtExecExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
      <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="QtExecExample" After="InstallFinalize"/>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>

Comment: A verbose log file `msiexec /l*v log.txt /i path\to\your.msi` should show the command being executed. Make sure it looks good and see why it doesn't want to launch your executable. You can paste it here for more information.

Comment: Rob-Sorry if this is a simpleton question but how can I get the log file for the msi if the msi is bundled in an .exe bundle?

Comment: If you're using using Burn from WiX v3.6+ then there is already a log file created for you in %TEMP%. If you are using some non-logging bootstrapper, try setting the MSI Logging policy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369776(v=vs.85).aspx